# add dependecies in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

When I try to add dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file in flutter web I get an error when trying the `pub get` command:

```
[retgoo_internal] pub get
Resolving dependencies...
Because every version of aiframework depends on flutter any from sdk which is forbidden, aiframework is forbidden.
So, because retgoo_internal depends on aiframework ^1.0.7+12, version solving failed.

Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`.
```

and my pubspec.yaml

```
name: retgoo_internal
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  aiframework: ^1.0.7+12
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
  http: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Comment: I think it is caused by your aiframework dependency. *Because every version of aiframework depends on flutter any from sdk which is forbidden, aiframework is forbidden.* Have your tried to remove this dependency?

Comment: not only aiframework pubs that can't, I can't try other pubs with the same problem

Comment: Are you running `flutter packages get` or `pub get`?

Comment: I tried the pub get, is there a problem?

Comment: What is the github link? If you can find that you could try using that link as a dependency or fork it and make the changes needed to get your app up and running.

Comment: The error message explicitly tells you to use `flutter packages get` if you are using Flutter, @OceanL :)

Comment: I already used flutter packages get and succeeded, but when I tried start debugging an error appeared: _[SEVERE]build_web_compilers:entrypoint on web/main.dart (cached): Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

`import 'package:aiframework/aiframework.dart';` from retgoo_internal|lib/activities/login_activity.dart at 7:1_

Comment: What happens if you remove `aiframework` from pubspec.yaml? I believe this is the root of your problem.

Comment: if I delete aiframework, there is no error and when debugging there is no problem

Comment: I tried trying to add `flutter:
    sdk: flutter` was successful, and when import packages were successful too, but it was strange when running there was an error in the flutter SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported yet in  flutter web like some packages but only way to solve this problem by take package' source code from github, take codes inside lib file inside package and put it in your project then fix errors may happen inside files by change path import to: import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart'; and some more changes may need to do it.

it worked 100% and so easy :)

[image]

Comment: used in the packages charts are charts_flutter or charts_common ??

Comment: charts_flutter but you must get charts_common under dependencies in   pubspeck.yaml

Comment: Great! How did you find out?

Answer (score -1):

try changing dependencies to:

```
dependencies:
  aiframework: ^1.0.7+12
  flutter_web:
  flutter_web_ui:
  http:
```

Comment: Leaving the field blank should not create another outcome compared to specifying any as a required version.

Comment: when I create a new web project and add a pub, it's the same. same error